# Two different series for $\frac{1}{x + 2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

> Find the appropriate power series for $f(x) = \frac{1}{x + 2} $

First method :  $\frac{1}{x + 2} =  \frac{1}{2(1 - (-\frac{x}{2}))} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}x^n$ , $|x|\lt2$

Second method : $\frac{1}{x + 2} = \frac{1}{1 - (-x-1)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x-1)^n$ , $-2 \lt x \lt 0$

Is there any problem in my answers ? Why these power series have different radii of convergence ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem (in principle; I haven't checked the details). Note that one power series has general term $\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}x^n$ and the other series has general term $(-1)^n(x+1)^n$.

A power series with general term $a_n(x-a)^n$ is said to be *centered around $a$*. For meromorphic functions (like rational functions), the radius of convergence for a power series turns out to be the distance from the center to the nearest pole.

$\frac{1}{x+2}$ has a pole at $x=-2$. Your first series is centered around $0$, and therefore has radius of convergence $2$, while your second series is centered at $-1$, and therefore has radius of convergence $-1$.

In fact, one can use this to gain a hint of the geometry of the complex plane using just the real numbers. The series of $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$  centered around $a\in\Bbb R$ has radius of convergence $\sqrt{a^2+1}$, hinting of a pole one unit away from $0$, perpendicular to the real line. We know its two poles as $\pm i$, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Convergence is doomed to fail at $x=-2$, hence the convergence radius when developing around $a$ cannot be larger than the distance from $a$ to $-2$, i.e., $|a+2|$ (and for higher reasons, this is indeed the radius of convergence). So when developing around $0$, the radius is $2$, when developing around $-1$, it is $1$ (and when developing around $42$ it would be $44$)

Answer (score 1):

Your computations are correct, but the radii of convergence aren't the same. It's $2$ for the first power series and $1$ for the second one.

Comment: If $x = -1$ then two series converge to different values . Why ?

Comment: @S.H.W What two different values are those?

Comment: @Arthur For the first series is $1$ and the second is $0$ .

Comment: @S.H.W When working with power series, you have to assume $0^0=1$. I would say you should use $0^0=1$ in general, but there are conventions to let it be undefined.

Comment: @Arthur Okay , thanks .

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the series centered at $x=0$ while the second one is the series centered at $x=-1$ therefore the radius of convergence are different.